# When does R perform automatic garbage collection?

Tags: r, garbage-collection

See the following example, garbage collection info is enforced with `gcinfo(T)`:

```
gcinfo(T)
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1e7)
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(1e6)
a <- x * z
rm(a)
```

This is what I see:

```
> gcinfo(T)
[1] FALSE
> set.seed(1)
> x <- rnorm(1e7)
Garbage collection 4 = 2+0+2 (level 2) ... 
11.6 Mbytes of cons cells used (47%)
3.1 Mbytes of vectors used (3%)
> y <- rnorm(100)
> z <- rnorm(1e6)
> a <- x * z
Garbage collection 5 = 2+0+3 (level 2) ... 
11.6 Mbytes of cons cells used (47%)
87.0 Mbytes of vectors used (44%)
> rm(a)
```

We can see that gc is performed when `x` and `a` are created. My question is:
When does R perform automatic gc, at fixed time intervals? at the end of session? after large object creation or rm?
what is the size limit for such large object?

Comment: From `?Memory`: "How much time R spends in the garbage collector will depend on these initial settings and on the trade-off the memory manager makes, when memory fills up, between collecting garbage to free up unused memory and growing these areas."

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, this is really vague, I failed to find any more detailed descriptions.